# How to remove a included layout from parent layout and add it again?

Tags: android

```
<FrameLayout android:id="@+id/layout1"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/panel_width"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="@integer/layout_gravity"
        android:paddingStart="@dimen/side_padding"
        android:paddingEnd="@dimen/side_padding"
        android:visibility="gone">
    <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:elevation="2dp"
            android:background="@drawable/background">
        <include layout="@layout/layout2" />
    </FrameLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Above layout is inside another layout and now I want to remove layout2 and add it again programatically how can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

For this you required to assign "id" to FrameLayout

```
<FrameLayout android:id="@+id/layout1"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/panel_width"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="@integer/layout_gravity"
    android:paddingStart="@dimen/side_padding"
    android:paddingEnd="@dimen/side_padding"
    android:visibility="gone">
<FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/layoutTest"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:elevation="2dp"
        android:background="@drawable/background">
    <include layout="@layout/layout2" />
</FrameLayout>
```

I assume you take references in .java file and after that use following code.

```
layoutTest.removeAllViews(); //To remove all views inside layout
layoutTest.addView(layout2); //Include view again.
```

Be-aware that your parent layout visibility is gone so run code when its visibility change to "visible".

Answer (score 0):

In java:

```
FrameLayout mWebContainer = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.FrameLayout1);

if (you need){
mWebContainer .setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}

else{
mWebContainer .setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

In xml:

```
<FrameLayout android:id="@+id/layout1"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/panel_width"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="@integer/layout_gravity"
    android:paddingStart="@dimen/side_padding"
    android:paddingEnd="@dimen/side_padding"
    android:visibility="gone">
<FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:elevation="2dp"
         android:id="@+id/FrameLayout1"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:background="@drawable/background">
    <include layout="@layout/layout2" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Actually my problem here to to refresh layout2 not just hiding and showing.
I tried using invalidate(), requestLayout() nothing worked for refreshing layout hence I thought to remove and add view.